# Counting similar items in array with mongodb aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm just learning mongodb aggregation framework
There are data in the the format below:

```
{
  "questionType": "multiple",
  "multipleOptions": ["first", "second", "third", "forth"],
  "answers": ["first", "second", "second", "first", "first", "forth"]
},
{
  "questionType": "multiple",
  "multipleOptions": ["awful", "bad", "soso", "good", "excellent"],
  "answers": ["bad", "bad", "good", "soso", "bad", "excellent", "awful", "soso"]
}
```

I want to aggregate these to something like this:

```
{
  "result": { "first": 3, "second": 2, "forth": 1 }
},
{
  "result": { "awful": 1, "bad": 3, "soso": 2, "good": 1, "excellent": 1 }
}
```

Or like this (no difference):

```
{
  "result": [["first", 3], ["second", 2], ["forth", 1]]
},
{
  "result": [["awful", 1], ["bad", 3], ["soso", 2], ["good", 1], ["excellent", 1]]
}
```

Is there a way to do this in a `$project` stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a cohort of array operators working in conjunction to produce the desired effect.

You essentially need an operation that creates an array of key/value pairs of the counts you need. This will then be converted to a hash map. The array of key value pairs is essentially a map which is constructed by looping through the `multipleOptions` array and checking the size of the elements that match in the answers array.

### TLDR;

The final pipeline you need to run follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
       "result":  {
           "$arrayToObject": {
               "$map": {
                    "input": { "$range": [ 0, { "$size": "$multipleOptions" } ] },
                    "as": "idx",
                    "in": {
                        "$let": {
                            "vars": {
                                "k": { 
                                    "$arrayElemAt": [ 
                                        "$multipleOptions", 
                                        "$$idx" 
                                    ] 
                                },
                                "v": { 
                                    "$size": {
                                        "$filter": {
                                            "input": "$answers",
                                            "as": "ans",
                                            "cond": {
                                                "$eq": [
                                                    "$$ans",
                                                    { 
                                                        "$arrayElemAt": [ 
                                                            "$multipleOptions", 
                                                            "$$idx" 
                                                        ] 
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "in": {  "k": "$$k", "v": "$$v" }
                        }
                    }
               }
           }
       }
    } }
])
```

---

To demonstrate this step by step, lets create an additional field in an aggregate operation, this field will be an array of the 
counts of the corresponding array element. We need something like

```
{
    "questionType": "multiple",
    "multipleOptions": ["awful", "bad", "soso", "good", "excellent"],
    "answersCount": [1, 3, 2, 1, 1],
    "answers": ["bad", "bad", "good", "soso", "bad", "excellent", "awful", "soso"]
}
```

To get this we need a way to loop through the `multipleOptions` and for each option, iterate the `answers` array, filter it and count the number of elements in the filtered array.  The pseudo-algorithm follows:

```
answersCount = []
for each elem in ["awful", "bad", "soso", "good", "excellent"]:
    filteredAnswers = [<answers array containing only elem>]
    count = filteredAnswers.length 
    answersCount.push(count)
```

In mongo, the filtering part can be done using [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) on the `answers` array and elements can be referenced with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/)

```
{
    "$filter": {
        "input": "$answers",
        "as": "ans",
        "cond": {
            "$eq": [
                "$$ans",
                { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$multipleOptions", "$$idx" ] }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The counts are derived using [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) on the above expression

```
{ 
    "$size": {
        "$filter": {
            "input": "$answers",
            "as": "ans",
            "cond": {
                "$eq": [
                    "$$ans",
                    { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$multipleOptions", "$$idx" ] }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For getting the outer loop, we can use [`$range`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) and [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) as

```
{
    "$map": {
        "input": { "$range": [ 0, { "$size": "$multipleOptions" } ] },
        "as": "idx",
        "in": {
            "$let": {
                "vars": {
                    "v": { 
                        "$size": {
                            "$filter": {
                                "input": "$answers",
                                "as": "ans",
                                "cond": {
                                    "$eq": [
                                        "$$ans",
                                        { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$multipleOptions", "$$idx" ] }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "in": "$$v"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will produce the `answersCount` in the following aggregate operation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": { 
       "answersCount": {
            "$map": {
                "input": { "$range": [ 0, { "$size": "$multipleOptions" } ] },
                "as": "idx",
                "in": {
                    "$let": {
                        "vars": {
                            "v": { 
                                "$size": {
                                    "$filter": {
                                        "input": "$answers",
                                        "as": "ans",
                                        "cond": {
                                            "$eq": [
                                                "$$ans",
                                                { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$multipleOptions", "$$idx" ] }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "in": "$$v" 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } }
])
```

To then get to the desired output, you need the `answersCount` to be an array of key/value pairs i.e.

```
{
    "answersCount": [
        { "k": "awful", "v": 1},
        { "k": "bad", "v": 3},
        { "k": "soso", "v": 2},
        { "k": "good", "v": 1},
        { "k": "excellent", "v": 1}
    ],
}
```

and when you apply [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) on the above expression i.e.

```
{ "$arrayToObject": {
    "answersCount": [
        { "k": "awful", "v": 1},
        { "k": "bad", "v": 3},
        { "k": "soso", "v": 2},
        { "k": "good", "v": 1},
        { "k": "excellent", "v": 1}
    ],
} }
```

you get

```
{
    "awful" : 1,
    "bad" : 3,
    "soso" : 2,
    "excellent" : 1,
    "good" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for "multi-stage grouping."   Let's begin with an `$unwind` of answers:

```
c = db.foo.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$answers"}
                      ]);
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "questionType" : "multiple",
    "multipleOptions" : [
        "first",
        "second",
        "third",
        "forth"
    ],
    "answers" : "first"
}
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "questionType" : "multiple",
    "multipleOptions" : [
        "first",
        "second",
        "third",
        "forth"
    ],
    "answers" : "second"
}
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "questionType" : "multiple",
    "multipleOptions" : [
        "first",
        "second",
        "third",
        "forth"
    ],
    "answers" : "second"
}
// ...
```

Now we have `answers` and `_id` as peers ready to group:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$answers"}
,{$group: {_id: {Xid:"$_id", answer:"$answers"}, n:{$sum:1} }}
]);
{ "_id" : { "Xid" : 1, "answer" : "awful" }, "n" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "Xid" : 1, "answer" : "excellent" }, "n" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "Xid" : 1, "answer" : "soso" }, "n" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "Xid" : 1, "answer" : "bad" }, "n" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "Xid" : 0, "answer" : "forth" }, "n" : 1 }
```

Now we group **again**, this time by the `_id.Xid` and then use `$push` to construct the output array of results:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$answers"}
,{$group: {_id: {Xid:"$_id", answer:"$answers"}, n:{$sum:1} }}
,{$group: {_id: "$_id.Xid", result: {$push: {answer: "$_id.answer", n: "$n" }} }}
]);
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "result" : [
        {
            "answer" : "forth",
            "n" : 1
        },
        {
            "answer" : "second",
            "n" : 2
        },
        {
            "answer" : "first",
            "n" : 3
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "result" : [
        {
            "answer" : "awful",
            "n" : 1
        },
        {
            "answer" : "excellent",
            "n" : 1
        },
        {
            "answer" : "soso",
            "n" : 2
        },
        {
            "answer" : "bad",
            "n" : 3
        },
        {
            "answer" : "good",
            "n" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

So in spirit we have a solution but to really press the point, we will use the `$arrayToObject` function to turn the array of options from the values of the `answer` key to keys in their own right.  To do so, we will name the `$push` object args `k` and `v` to properly drive the function:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$answers"}
,{$group: {_id: {Xid:"$_id", answer:"$answers"}, n:{$sum:1} }}
,{$group: {_id: "$_id.Xid", QQ: {$push: {k: "$_id.answer", v: "$n" }} }}
,{$project: {_id: true, result: {$arrayToObject: "$QQ"} }}
                      ]);
```

which yields:

```
{ "_id" : 0, "result" : { "forth" : 1, "second" : 2, "first" : 3 } }
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "result" : {
        "awful" : 1,
        "excellent" : 1,
        "soso" : 2,
        "bad" : 3,
        "good" : 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to do it in one project stage, thanks for your solution by the way.